# How to generate Sitemap in Strapi v3.6.8 with strapi-plugin.sitemap v1.2.5

Tags: next.js, sitemap, strapi

I am using Strapi v3.6.8 and installed strapi-plugin-sitemap 1.2.5.

After I fill the data in the plugin:

- Hostname: localhost:1337
- Include home page: ON
- Exclude drafts: ON

I also enabled all of the possibilities in the Settings for public and authenticated roles.

And choose my Content Type -> Page with filled UID Field, with "priority 1", change request "always" and area "area".

When I click the generate sitemap I get error "An Error occurred" and nothing happens.

When I am trying to access http://localhost:1337/sitemap/ I get an error **:**

```
{
  "statusCode":500,
  "error":"Internal Server Error",
  "message":"An internal server error occurred"
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Strapi settings-> Roles-> Public -> scroll all the way to down and open the Sitemap (click the dropdown). There you need to check all the boxes.

Hope u get it.